# Clojure maps to named keys syntax

Tags: clojure

I'm guessing there's a simple way to do this that I'm not finding. I want to pass a map to a method that takes named values bound to keys, e.g.

> (defn my-method [ & {:keys  [ a b c ] }] ...

This works if called with e.g.

> (my-method :a 1 :b 2 :c 3)

but I'd like to call it with a supplied map, e.g. something that looks like

> (def m  {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
>
> (my-method m)

Is there a simple method to transform the map to the required argument list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just drop the ampersand:

```
> (defn my-method [{:keys [a b c]}] (+ a b c))
> (my-method m)
6
```

Comment: The question asked "given a method of this shape, how do I call it?". This answer is of the form: "change the method", so I do not think it is a good answer. But perhaps it was not a good question. :)

Comment: Ah, I read it as calling a method that he wrote. Without being able to change the method, I don't think there's a better solution than your answer.

Answer (score 5):

It ain't pretty but:

```
(apply my-method (mapcat identity m))
```

or as suggested in the comments:

```
(apply my-method (apply concat m))
```

Comment: `mapcat identity` is weird. Sometimes I write `mapcat seq` because it's shortest, but `apply concat` is sorta the traditional way.

Comment: I think I saw `mapcat identity` from someone many years ago (maybe chouser, I blame everything clever on chouser) and it stuck. Agreed that `apply concat` seems a better representation of intent.

Comment: I've found it useful to define: `(defn apply-map [f & args] (apply f (concat (butlast args) (apply concat (last args)))))`